# How to decrypt data that is encrypted by OpenSSL with RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING using NCryptDecrypt?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have difficulty to decrypt data being encrypted using OpenSSL and RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING padding option.

What I am doing is:

```
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hCryptAlg = NULL;
    BCRYPT_OAEP_PADDING_INFO paddingInfo = { 0 };
    DWORD cbDecryptedMessage;
    BYTE* pbDecryptedMessage = NULL;

    paddingInfo.pszAlgId = BCRYPT_SHA1_ALGORITHM;

    // Open an algorithm handle.
    BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&hCryptAlg, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0);

    // Calculate the required buffer 
    NCryptDecrypt(m_hKeyContextFull, (LPBYTE)pEncrypted, encryptedLenInBytes, &paddingInfo, NULL, cbDecryptedMessage, &outputDataLen, NCRYPT_PAD_OAEP_FLAG | NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG);

    // After required buffer is allocated...
    NCryptDecrypt(m_hKeyContextFull, (LPBYTE)pEncrypted, encryptedLenInBytes, &paddingInfo, pbDecryptedMessage, cbDecryptedMessage, &outputDataLen, NCRYPT_PAD_OAEP_FLAG | NCRYPT_SILENT_FLAG);
```

It fails with NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER (0x80090027). I tried different flags but none of them works.

Note: m_hKeyContextFull has already been retrieved using CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey function call:

```
 m_hSystemStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, m_storeName.c_str());

 m_pCertWithKeys = CertFindCertificateInStore(m_hSystemStore, SupportedEncodings, 0, CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR, m_certName.c_str(), NULL);

 // Obtain the private key from the certificate.
 DWORD m_KeyContextSpec = 0;
 HCRYPTPROV_OR_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE m_hKeyContextFull;
 CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(m_pCertWithKeys, CRYPT_ACQUIRE_SILENT_FLAG | CRYPT_ACQUIRE_PREFER_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, NULL, &m_hKeyContextFull, &m_KeyContextSpec, &m_KeyContextMustBeReleased);
```

Note: All error checkings have been removed from code for readability.

Is there any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the `m_hKeyContextFull` come from? Where is the RSA key loaded from etc.? Very incomplete code. Post a **full** example, not just a snippet.

Comment: `paddingInfo` is invalid.

Comment: Hi Henno, Thank you for your comment, I actually did not want to make complexity by posting a full sample, the key is loaded from Windows Key Store using CertOpenStore then a call to CertFindCertificateInStore. All unit tests to encrypt and decrypt are passing. The problem though is when I am trying to decrypt a data that is encrypted using OpenSSL with RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING flag specified. I can decrypt it by SoftHSM but in MSCRYPTO I just fail. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by making paddingInfo valid:

```
BCRYPT_OAEP_PADDING_INFO paddingInfo;
paddingInfo.pszAlgId = BCRYPT_SHA1_ALGORITHM;
paddingInfo.pbLabel = NULL;
paddingInfo.cbLabel = 0;
```

The current standard has the empty string label (see [RFC 3447](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt)).

Moreover, as to `pbDecryptedMessage`:

> If this parameter is NULL, this function will calculate the size needed for the decrypted data and return the size in the location pointed to by the pcbResult parameter.

So it won't decrypt anyway. You need to allocate the buffer first to the right size; a lot of Windows API's work that way: first call it with output buffer NULL and you get back the needed size somehow, in this case in `outputDataLen` (which you should declare!). Then allocate the outbufbuffer to that size, and call the function again with the fresh buffer, and the correct length in `cbDecryptedMessage`. After use, free the buffer again of course. But your comment claims to have done so?

Another suspicious fact: You use NCryptDecrypt so the first argument, should
be a hKey of the right type, while `m_hKeyContextFull` does not seem to have that type. `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` will get you an old style key handle.
You cannot mix these different Windows CryptoAPI's. 
Maybe look at the [NcryptImportKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptimportkey) function, to transfer it.

Comment: Thanks Henno, I will try your suggestion and let you know about the result.

Comment: NCryptImportKey imports from a memory buffer, the key has to be exported to the buffer first, but the result was the same and I could not get it working. Is there any incompatibility between OpenSSL and Microsoft CNG and KSP?

Comment: I could successfully decode a string encrypted with openssl+OAEP in this manner. This is helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `NCrypt` series of interfaces, but we implemented something similar recently in a library using the `BCrypt` series of interfaces. Here is the function in question, which can be seen in greater context [here](https://gitlab.com/ubiqsecurity/ubiq-c-cpp/-/blob/master/src/lib/wincrypt.c).

In our case `prvblbtyp` is `LEGACY_RSAPRIVATE_BLOB` and `prvblbbuf` and `prvblbblen` are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/rsa-schannel-key-blobs#private-key-blobs).

```c
static
int
asymmetric_decrypt(
    const wchar_t * const prvblbtyp,
    const void * const prvblbbuf, const size_t prvblblen,
    const void * const ctbuf, const size_t ctlen,
    void ** const ptbuf, size_t * const ptlen)
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE halg;
    int res;

    res = INT_MIN;
    if (BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
            &halg, BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM, NULL, 0) == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hkey;

        if (BCryptImportKeyPair(
                halg,
                NULL, prvblbtyp, &hkey,
                (void *)prvblbbuf, prvblblen,
                0) == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
            BCRYPT_OAEP_PADDING_INFO inf;
            ULONG len;

            inf.pszAlgId = BCRYPT_SHA1_ALGORITHM;
            inf.pbLabel = NULL;
            inf.cbLabel = 0;

            /*
             * decrypt first with a NULL output buffer.
             * this returns the size necessary for the buffer.
             */
            if (BCryptDecrypt(
                    hkey,
                    (void *)ctbuf, ctlen,
                    &inf,
                    NULL, 0,
                    NULL, 0, &len,
                    BCRYPT_PAD_OAEP) == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                void * buf;

                /*
                 * allocate the required buffer
                 * and decrypt again
                 */
                res = -ENOMEM;
                buf = malloc(len);
                if (buf) {
                    res = INT_MIN;
                    if (BCryptDecrypt(
                            hkey,
                            (void *)ctbuf, ctlen,
                            &inf,
                            NULL, 0,
                            buf, len, &len,
                            BCRYPT_PAD_OAEP) == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                        *ptbuf = buf;
                        *ptlen = len;
                        res = 0;
                    } else {
                        free(buf);
                    }
                }
            }

            BCryptDestroyKey(hkey);
        }

        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(halg, 0);
    }

    return res;
}
```